# Fastest way to calculate the sum of specific regions of an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, numpy, sum

Given the following data (in python 2.7):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14])
b = np.array([8,2,3])
```

I want to get the sum of the first 8 elements in `a`, then the sum of the 9 and 10 element and in the end the last 3 (basic the information in `b`). The desired output is:

```
[36, 19, 37]
```

I can do this with for loops and such, but there must be a more pythonic way and a more efficient way of doing!

Comment: You're using numpy. Use an array based solution. Numpy's [sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum) and [slice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) operations are far faster than anything in Python itself, though your data is too small to matter.

Answer (score 9):

That's easy with [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
result = [part.sum() for part in np.split(a, np.cumsum(b))[:-1]]
print(result)
>>> [36, 19, 37]
```

Comment: If you care about performance - especially if these subarrays are small - then you should use `part.sum()` instead of `np.sum(part)`.

Comment: you can also do this with `np.add.reduceat(a, np.cumsum(b)[:-1])`

Comment: @MSeifert I'm taking your word for it and changing it in the answer, but do have a reference to a benchmark about it, or just some explanation?

Comment: @DanielF That would make a fine answer on it's own :) (if it works)

Comment: @DanielF That's awesome, didn't know that one, you should post that as your own answer, it looks more on point than mine tbh.

Comment: @MSeifert this arrays are large... What is the difference between part.sum() and np.sum(part)?

Comment: `np.sum` has much more overhead than calling the `sum` method directly.

Answer (score 8):

A much faster way than `np.split` is:

```
np.add.reduceat(a, np.r_[0, np.cumsum(b)[:-1]])
```

What this does:

1. Creates an array of ascending indices out of `b` corresponding to the ranges you want to sum over - for simplicity, you can assign `c = np.r_[0, np.cumsum(b)[:-1]]` which for your example would be `array([0, 8, 10])` - which is `0` followed all but the last element of the cumulative sum of `b` (`np.cumsum(b) -> array([8, 10, 13])` (the domain of `np.ufunc.reduceat` is exclusive of the endpoint, so we have to get rid of that `13`)
2. `np.ufunc.reduceat(a, c)` `reduce`s  `a` by `ufunc` (in this case, `add`)  over ranges specified by `c[i]:c[i+1]`.  When `i+1` would overflow `c`, it instead `reduce`s over `c[i]:-1`
3. `reduce` just condenses an array to a single value.  For example, `np.add.reduce(a)` is equivalent to (but slower than) `np.sum(a)` (which is in turn slower than `a.sum()`).  However, since `reduceat` pushes the `for` loop in the answer by @jdehsa out of python and into `numpy` core compiled c-code, it is much faster.

Speed test:

```
b = np.random.randint(1,10,(10000,))
a = np.random.randint(1,10,(np.sum(b),))

%timeit np.add.reduceat(a, np.r_[0, np.cumsum(b)[:-1]])
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 µs per loop
%timeit [part.sum() for part in np.split(a, np.cumsum(b))[:-1]]
10 loops, best of 3: 44.6 ms per loop
```

And with the added benefit of not wasting memory creating a temporary `split` copy of `a`

Comment: Should have known something was up when @MSeifert started hedging "if it works."  Fixed now.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, what your solution does? It looks a little bit like magic ;)

Comment: Check out [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html#numpy.ufunc.reduceat).  `add` is one of the simplest of the [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) family.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method of the [`np.add` ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html). You just need to add a zero in front of your indices and discard the last index (if it covers the complete array):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14])
>>> b = np.array([8,2,3])
>>> np.add.reduceat(a, np.append([0], np.cumsum(b)[:-1]))
array([36, 19, 37], dtype=int32)
```

The `[:-1]` discards the last index and the `np.append([0],` adds a zero in front of the indices.

Note that this is a slightly adapted variant of [DanielFs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482356/5393381).

If you don't like the `append` you could also create a new array yourself containing the indices:

```
>>> b_sum = np.zeros_like(b)
>>> np.cumsum(b[:-1], out=b_sum[1:])  # insert the cumsum in the b_sum array directly
>>> np.add.reduceat(a, b_sum)
array([36, 19, 37], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: if b is very large isn't that append expensive?

Comment: Shouldn't be.  It's only done once and over one dimension.  Considering the overhead of all the indexing and adding it should be negligible

Comment: @DiogoSantos It depends (it's done only once here so it's just an `O(n)` operation like all the other steps), I also included an approach that doesn't need the `append`. You might want to check which one is faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you have to use the elements in b :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14])
b = np.array([8,2,3])

c = np.array([np.sum(a[:b[0]]),np.sum(a[b[0]:b[0]+b[1]]),np.sum(a[-b[2]:])])
```

Answer (score 1):

**A solution using numba**

There is already a good pythonic answer from @Daniel F. I wan't to show a alternative less pythonic, but faster solution. You can use loops in Python, but if you wan't to get reasonable speed you have to use a compiler. Numba is very easy to use so I wan't to give an example here.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time
def main():
    b = np.random.randint(1,10,(10000,))
    a = np.random.randint(1,10,(np.sum(b),))

    nb_splitsum = nb.njit(nb.int32[:](nb.int32[:], nb.int32[:]),nogil=True)(splitsum)

    t1=time.time()
    for i in xrange(0,1000):
        c=nb_splitsum(a,b)

    print("Numba Solution")
    print(time.time()-t1)

    t1=time.time()
    for i in xrange(0,1000):
        c=np.add.reduceat(a, np.r_[0, np.cumsum(b)[:-1]])
    print("Numpy Solution")
    print(time.time()-t1)

def splitsum(a,b):
    sum=np.empty(b.shape[0],dtype=np.int32)
    ii=0
    for i in range(0,b.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,b[i]):
            sum[i]+=a[ii]
            ii+=1
    return sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


#Output
Numba Solution
0.125
Numpy Solution
0.280999898911
```

You have a compilation overhead of about 0.15s on my machine. But when the function is compiled, the solution shown above is about twice as fast than the pure numpy solution.